# How to Expand rows in SQL to analyse data counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table (lets call it MyTable) of the following type:

```
 Name     | Date             | no_appointments    | Class |
----------+------------------+--------------------+-------+
 A        | 2019-04-01       | 2                  |   1   |
 B        | 2019-05-01       | 4                  |   0   |
```

And I would like to expand the rows by repeating each of them the amount of times specified by no_appointments (the equivalent of R's `expandRows()` function).

I am using PostgreSQL 12.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.*, n.n
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, t.no_appointments, 1) gs(n);
```

Actually Postgres allows the syntax as:

```
select t.*, generate_series(1, t.no_appointments, 1) as n
from t;
```

However, I don't like changing the number of rows in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can simply use `generate_series()` and a lateral join:

```
select t.*, x.i
from mytable t
cross join lateral generate_series(1, t.no_appointments) as x(i)
```

The last column in the resultset contains the iteration number of each row. You can remove if it this is not a sensible information for you.